# bash process data

Tags: bash

the original file input_file.txt is sth like:

```
A: 46274
B: 43274
C: 47242
```

I want to subtract all these numbers by a certain number, say 40000, then output the results to another file output_file.txt like:

```
6274
3274
7242
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input.txt**

```
A: 46274 
B: 43274 
C: 47242
```

**Unix Solution**

```
$> awk -F " " '{print $2-40000}' Input.txt > Output.txt
```

**Perl Solution**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    my @a=`cat /home/Input.txt`;
    foreach my $b (@a)
    {
            chomp($b);
            my ($c1,$c) = split (':',$b);
            chomp($c);
            $d= $c - 40000;
            print "$d\n";
    }
```

Execute and Redirect the output of the script to Output.txt

**Output.txt**

```
6274
3274
7242
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk` to do it. For example:

```
$ cat in.txt 
A: 46274
B: 43274
C: 47242
$ awk '{ print $2-74 }' in.txt 
46200
43200
47168
$
```

If just for the sake of experiment you want to do it with bash itself and not using tools like `awk`, you could do this as well:

```
$ while read a b; do echo $(($b - 74)); done <./in.txt 
46200
43200
47168
```